# What type of human being can help? Which one specifically?

Tags: human-rights, probate, civil

I have with me more than 1500 documents associated with abduction and human trafficking as well as probate fraud and political corruption associated with the district attorney's Office in Orange County and the public defender's office. While making every effort to try to protect law enforcement I've been unable to contact the FBI successfully or have anyone even file a case report on the matter and have had my rights violated in every way. All these people are robbing individuals of their inheritance. I have no ill will about the situation but I'm drastically concerned since they impounded our truck and sold it off within 3 weeks. Every time we've tried to escape the county we literally have been physically stopped while being extorted and threatened. I'm scared that they might literally throw us in jail and we'll never be seen again at this point. All the attempts to contact a civil rights lawyer have failed and I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: The possibility that every individual in every law enforcement agency is conspiring against you is much smaller that the possibility that you are suffering from [persecutory delusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecutory_delusion) or some other form of [paranoia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paranoia). I would start by seeing a mental health professional.

Answer (score 1):

So you are convinced that the government and police of Orange Country, California, conspire against you.

- Try reaching the ACLU. The Southern California branch has an [online contact form](https://www.aclusocal.org/en/seeking-legal-help-aclu).
- Hire a lawyer to represent you. If you *should* be locked up, the lawyer could follow up on that.